# three js update tubegeometry not visible r100

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, updates

I have a function that generates new tube each frame following the movement of a mesh. The function that does the updating of the tubegeometry looks like the following:

```
function UpdateKettingMeshes(kettingMeshes, kraalElements, kettingCurvesArray, kettingShapeArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < kettingMeshes.length; i++) {
        const element = kettingMeshes[i];
        const elCurve = kettingCurvesArray[i];
        const elShape = kettingShapeArray[i];
        elCurve.v0.copy(kraalElements[i].kraal.position.clone());
        elCurve.v1.copy(kraalElements[i].kraal.position.clone().add(elShape.controlPointDirection1.clone().multiplyScalar(elShape.controlPointPower1)));
        elCurve.v2.copy(kraalElements[i + 1].kraal.position.clone().add(elShape.controlPointDirection2.clone().multiplyScalar(elShape.controlPointPower2)));
        elCurve.v3.copy(kraalElements[i + 1].kraal.position.clone());
        const geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( elCurve, 80, 1.2, 8, false );
        element.geometry.vertices = geometry.vertices;
        element.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }

    return kettingMeshes;
}
```

I call this function each frame like so:

```
kettingMeshData = UpdateKettingMeshes(kettingMeshData, kralenObjects, kettingCurveData, kettingShapeData);
```

this works fine, no errors and when i `console.log` the `kettingMeshData` and check if the vertices have been updated i see that is the case see images below:

previous frame:
[image]
current frame: 
[image]

But the problem is that the actual mesh does not change in the scene? why is it not updating?

side note, all tube meshes are located in a three.group().

if something is not clear let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: (1) Avoid calling `clone()` every frame. (2) Avoid calling `new` every frame. (3) Assigning a new array to `geometry.vertices` is invalid three.js code; instead, just change the values of the existing array elements.

Comment: yeah i know it is not optimal code, if you could advice me on how to do it more efficiently that would be very much appreciated!! and thanks for the array thing i will change it :)